# print the letters that repeat more than 2 times from a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print the letters that repeat more than 2 times from a string.

I have finished printing the frequency of all letters but I don't know how to filter the result.
here is the code:

```py
import re

sentence = "Xin chao Python! Python rat thu vi! Toi rat thich no-P"
#remove special character
str = re.sub('\W+','', sentence )

frequency = []
dict = {}

for i in set(str):
    b = str.count(i, 0, len(str))
    dict[i] = b

for i in sorted(dict, key=dict.get, reverse=True):
    frequency.append((i, dict[i]))


print(frequency)
```

The result I have:

`[('h', 6), ('t', 6), ('o', 5), ('i', 4), ('n', 4), ('P', 3), ('a', 3), ('r', 2), ('c', 2), ('y', 2), ('u', 1), ('X', 1), ('v', 1), ('T', 1)]`

I want to print just the letters repeats more than 2 time but I stuck :(

and I want to print the result in the format as 5 Letters each line.

Hope you guys can help me.

Many thanks<3

Comment: Please format your question correctly, and review it to make sure everything is correct before submitting it. If you are unsure how to do that refer to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @OlivierMelançon so sorry I have searched for how to include code into the ques but I don't know how till now :(

Answer (score 2):

One good approach is to use a `collections.Counter` and then filter its content with a list-comprehension.

```
from collections import Counter

my_string = "Xin chao Python! Python rat thu vi! Toi rat thich no-P"

counter = Counter(my_string)

letters = [(l, count) for l, count in counter.items() if count > 1]

print(letters)
# result: [('i', 4), ('n', 4), (' ', 10), ('c', 2), ('h', 6), ('a', 3), ('o', 5), ('P', 3), ('y', 2), ('t', 6), ('!', 2), ('r', 2)]
```

You might notice that punctuation and spaces have been counted as well. If you do not want this, then use this version of the list-comprehension to filter out characters which are not `ascii_letters`:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_letters

my_string = "Xin chao Python! Python rat thu vi! Toi rat thich no-P"

counter = Counter(my_string)

letters = [(l, count) for l, count in counter.items() if count > 1 and l in ascii_letters]

print(letters)
# result: [('i', 4), ('n', 4), ('c', 2), ('h', 6), ('a', 3), ('o', 5), ('P', 3), ('y', 2), ('t', 6), ('r', 2)]
```

If you do not care about the number of occurences, but only the letters, then use this list-comprehension instead:

```
letters = [l for l, count in counter.items() if count > 1 and l in ascii_letters]
```

Comment: Many thanks. so grateful to you. But in my situation, the dictionary is compulsory :(

Comment: @Luong A Counter is a subclass of a dictionary and its more efficient than you implementation. Why do you want a dict? Is this a homework?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the list for this. Just iterate through the dictionary and check if the count > 2.

```
line = ''

for i in dict:
    if dict[i] > 2:
       line+=i

        if len(line) == 5:
            print(line)
            line = ''
if line:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to Olivier Melançon's answer, to achieve the final format you desire:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_letters

my_string = "Xin chao Python! Python rat thu vi! Toi rat thich no-P"

counter = Counter(my_string)

#if you want to include whitespace and punctuation as characters
letters = [(l, count) for l, count in counter.items() if count > 1]

#if you want to include only alphabetic characters
letters = [(l, count) for l, count in counter.items() if count > 1 and l in ascii_letters]

c = 0
for letter in letters:
    if c == 4:
        print(letter[0])
        c = 0

    else:
        print(letter[0], end="")
        c += 1
```

Comment: it seems there is something wrong while its lack of 5th letter in each line :(

Comment: My apologies, there was a typo in my answer, ill update it

Comment: it prints 5th very smooth but it lacks all of the repeat value numbers :(